# What build tool should I use for MonoTouch development?

Tags: iphone, build, xamarin.ios

I want to create build scripts for my MonoTouch apps. Basically, something that'll compile the application, run tests, zip into into an IPA file, check the source into SVN and write a message to the test log and email the beta testers. Just small scale stuff.

What should I use? I'm looking at xbuild, but wondering if it's quite there yet. What are other MonoTouch developers using? Are there any sample scripts I could start from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "mdtool build" command, this is part of MonoDevelop.